# Will it damage my iPad if I use an iPhone charger to charge it?

Tags: iphone, ipad, charging

I have the opposite issue of this question: [Is it OK to charge my iPhone with my iPad charger?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2017/is-it-ok-to-charge-my-iphone-with-my-ipad-charger)

I want to use my iPhone charger (plugged directly into main electricity) to charge my iPad. I've noticed that the charger gets quite warm when charging the iPad (not iPhone).

Is it unsafe to charge the iPad via the iPhone 5W charger?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**

I mix and match my chargers often, the only disadvantage is that the iPhone charger charges slower according to a lot of sources, but I have yet to experience it. I still have an iPhone 3G charger I use as a spare at work to charge my iPad on occasion.

Interestingly I have never noticed my chargers getting hot either, but will admit I have never actively looked.

Looking at the Charging Tips [here](http://www.apple.com/batteries/ipad.html) the reason for the slower charge is that the iPhone charger is 5W compared to 10W for the iPad, based on wattage alone, I can't see how you would damage the iPad, I would suspect using a higher wattage might however.

Comment: Using a higher wattage charger won't hurt a device (provided it has the same voltage). If the device can use the higher watts, then it will be supplied. If not, then it just gets what is needed. So say the iPhone requires 6W and the iPad 8W. If you used the 10W charge on the iPhone, it would take the 6W it needs, no more. Only the increase in actual voltage damages electronics.

Comment: No problem. Here is what Apple says "For instance If you have a MacBook (13-inch Late 2009) that normally uses a 60W adapter, you can also use an 85W adapter with that computer. You would not use a 45W adapter with that computer; it would not provide enough power for that MacBook. Using an adapter of higher wattage than the adapter that came with the computer will not cause the computer to charge more quickly or otherwise operate any differently than using the adapter that came with the computer." http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2346

Comment: It will in fact charge a lot slower, and it is quite noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Any charger circuit has inner impedence,the wattage bigger,the inner impedence
Will be smaller,the voltage drop while charging also smaller,the result is a charging time litter bit longer.On other side,the inner impedence contain resistance,it cause the charger warm ( temperature rise),so if you use the 5w
Charger to charge an iPad,you can feel the adapter warmer than used on iPhone
. But if the temerature keep stable,it is safety.

Misanlu in Sydney