# Can I (or should I) use a MacBook charger on my iPhone?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, charging, power

I recently got a MacBook with the USB-C charger. It comes with a 29-watt power brick, and I was wondering if I should use this to charge my iPhone. I've heard that the iPad power brick (I think 10 watts) charges the phone faster. I don't expect to be able to charge the phone proportionally faster, but would the MacBook brick damage the phone? I would rather only have to carry around one charging brick around campus. Also, I have a USB to USB-C converter.

Comment: Hi. Could you possibly add pictures of the connectors (the port on the MacBook, both ends of the cord, the port on the "power brick") for those who are curious but have never seen the new MacBook model nor a USB-C cable yet? Thanks. PS: This is really amazing if Apple is going to embrace a common (though not widespread so far) standard finally...

Comment: Check out Apple's own statement about it: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202105 seems to be tested and safe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unless there is some reason to the contrary that I'm not aware of, yes, you can use your MacBook charger with your iPhone. The power adapter will only convert as much power as is drawn, and the iPhone will only draw as much power as it needs.

(Note that it is not a good idea to charge your MacBook with an iPhone or iPad charger!)

Comment: for the same reasons addressed here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/2017/12285

Comment: Can you elaborate (or link to a source) why it's not a good idea to charge a MacBook with an iPhone charger?

Comment: @phihag See my comment above.

Comment: I apologize, but I am confused. Your comment links to a question like this one, which asks whether it's ok to charge an iPhone with a high-powered adapter. My question is about charging a MacBook with a lower-powered adapter. This answer says that it is **not** a good idea, without elaborating why. To get a clear answer, I have asked [my own question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/273560/3367). I'd appreciate it if you could write an answer there. Thanks!

Comment: @phihag Simply, an iPad requires twice as much power as an iPhone charger provides, and a MacBook Pro requires an *order of magnitude* more power than an iPhone charger provides.

Answer (score 4):

This video shows that you can use MacBook 12" 29W USB-C Power Adapter with iPad and iPhone.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWzbaH24Q0Y

Comment: I am sorry Max Ried. I just edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at least for the iPhone 6S using the Apple USB-C to Lighning 2m cable. I just started using it this week with mine and haven't had any issues.

For a few years I've charged my iPhone with an iPad charger. Not sure if the 29W charger is faster, but at least it seems just as fast.

Also, I heard in a podcast about videos warning about USB-C to USB converters. As long as you trust the one you have and it's not sketchy, I think it should be OK.

Comment: Yeah, I bought the proprietary one from Apple because I was worried about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My Macbook Pro 13inch Late 2016 61W USB-C Power brick says output: 20.3V/3A, 9V/3A or 5.2V/2.4A.
So yes you can charge your iphone with the Macbook charger.
The people at the Apple store just don't know what they are selling.

Answer (score 1):

Using a USB-C to USB-A adapter and a USB-A to Lighting cable to your MacBook charger means your iPhone gets no more power than using a common 12 watt USB-A charger, both cases means the phone sees 5 volts @ 2.4 amps.

With the MacBook 29 watt charger and a USB-C to Lightning cable the iPhone sees more power but Apple doesn't say how much more.  It's safe or Apple would not allow it.  I charge my iPhone from my 61 watt and 87 watt MacBook chargers regularly with nothing wrong that I can see.

If you wish to carry around just one charger then I would suggest getting something bigger to charge both.  With the phone plugged into the laptop, and the laptop plugged into the charger there's potential to charge both more quickly with a power powerful power supply.

A quick look at the Apple store shows me that Apple discontinued all but three USB-C chargers, 30W, 61W, and 96W.  This makes a bit of sense because there's not much need to keep a 87 watt supply around when it's going to be about the same size, mass, and cost of their 96 watt supply.  It's really impossible to get a supply that's too big because the phone and laptop will take only so much power and a bigger supply isn't going to damage anything.  Too small though and you will be waiting for your devices to charge when you would not have to with a larger charger.

With a 30 watt charger being the default for either device it would seem logical that to charge both at the same time with their maximum charge rate it would take the 61 watt charger.  The MacBook will pass power just fine to the phone so both can charge quickly.  Charging either alone with the charger will be fine as well.

If a new charger is something that you might not see a need for at this time then that's fine, the charger you have will not overheat or anything.  The phone and laptop are smart enough to share the power and still charge, if just more slowly than with a larger charger.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208137

> You can fast charge your iPhone 8 and later up to 50 percent battery in around 30 minutes.
>
> Fast charging works when you use an Apple USB-C to Lightning cable and one of these adapters:
>
> - Apple 18W, 20W, 29W, 30W, 61W, 87W, or 96W USB-C Power Adapter
> - A comparable third-party USB-C power adapter that supports USB Power Delivery (USB-PD)