# Can I charge my MacBook with a phone charger?

Tags: macbook-pro, charging

Can I use a phone USB-C charger (e.g. the [from google](https://store.google.com/product/usb_type_c_18w_power_adapter)) to charge my 2016 MacBook Pro? How about a USB-A charger with a USB A->C cable?

Physically it fits, but [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/212551/3367) says that *it is not a good idea*, without elaborating why.

Comment: You can recharge usb-c powered MacBooks, in fact I'm doing it right now. It's reeealy slow though.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't do this is a matter of input.

The 13" MBP has a 61W charger - a lot more than your typical phone charger brick. Check your phone brick and see how much of a difference there is.

Your Macbook would probably not even accept the charge because it would be so low

Comment: Not quite true.  The capacity of the charger shipped with a MacBook (or any device really) is designed such that it can power the device at full load, and charge it, simultaneously.  An iPhone charger can’t do this for a MBP, e.g., but it can provide 10W or 20W (or whatever) of that power budget.  If you’re using less than that, it will charge — slowly.  If you’re using more, it will supply part of the total consumption, and the battery will cover the deficit.  You’ll still discharge the battery, just slower.  I’ve charged my MBP from a printer - 5V, 500mA.  It works in a pinch…